# How to modify maps created in carto builder using carto js?

Tags: cartodb

I am a new Carto user, and would like to add dynamic pie charts (that update with the selection of a district) and a search box to my carto builder maps. One of the ways I assume this could be done is through Carto js. How to start using carto js to modif my carto builder maps?

Comment: It's goign to be hard to get this answered (too broad). Try to to show what you tried already.

Comment: Well,I tried looking at the various possible widgets in Carto, but although the ones that are present are pretty good, they are a bit limited in variety. I also explored the possibility of linking the map data with other data viz apps such as infogram but could not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can start reading [the documentation](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/). There are plenty of examples on how to load data, and create widgets. If you find any issue specific to the functionality you can post here for more detailed answers but as `@swa66` commented, your question is too broad at this moment.

On the other hand, just as a note, CARTO does not have a direct way to work from CARTO.js with BUILDER maps, you need to put your SQL and CartoCSS on your JavaScript code to retrieve and work with your data.

**Disclaimer**: I work at CARTO.